# /revisions/{ids} returns wrong body

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, revisions

Since a couple of days, the [/revisions/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-guids) method returns a wrong value for the `body` field. An example is [this Ask Different post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/56682/revisions). When viewing the (only) [revision](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/56682/1) on the website, you see that the broken image is rendered as a link:

[image]

But [this call](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/revisions/e2592758-9510-463a-bcde-7a9fa9682dd6?site=apple&filter=!*JxbFHu6gmE0LFV7) to /revisions/{ids} claims it's rendered as an image:

[image]

The /posts/{ids} method does give the right `body` value; [this call](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/56682?site=apple&filter=!9Z(-wu0BT) produces

[image]

(I'm pretty sure this is a recent bug, since a lot of the automated test cases for my [Broken Image Repairer](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) suddenly started to fail after having worked correctly for half a year.)

Comment: Confirmed.  Somebody's not using DRY code...